# recursive loop in Matlab can't iterate

Tags: matlab

everyone. I have a problem with loops. It only executed once and is not iterating.

I am trying to find the surface temperature of a spacecraft as a function of time. The radiative heat flow depends on the current temperature, so the next temperature in the loop should depend on the temperature a second ago. This isn't the whole script, but can anyone tell me what's wrong with my loop?

Thanks!

```
% Starting with given surface and interior temperatures, find each new
% temperature with each heat flux every second through one orbit.

timeline = 1:1:time1;
Ts = zeros(size(timeline));
Ts(1) = 240; % initial surface temperature, Kelvins`

for n = 2:length(time1)
    Ts(n) = (solarflux + IRs - (sigma*ems_mli*surfarea*(Ts(n-1)^4)))/(m*c) + Ts(n-1);
end

%% Plotting

figure(1)
plot(timeline,Ts)
xlabel('seconds');
ylabel('surface temperature (Kelvins)');
```

Comment: This isn't recursion and `time1` isn't defined. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: In addition to the comment from excaza (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733803/recursive-loop-in-matlab-cant-iterate#comment64843709_38733803) you may want to look at the debugger http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html . This should solve your problem quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed some errors:

- `n=2:length(time1)` should be `n = 2:length(timeline)` because `time1` is a scalar
- I used length instead of size in `zeros(size(timeline)` and I added 1 as an input to make it a vector of the same size as timeline.

Here is the code:

```
timeline = 1:1:time1;                              % your time array
Ts = zeros(1,length(timeline));                    % preallocate memory for Ts
Ts(1) = 240;                                       % initial surface temperature, Kelvins

for n = 2:length(timeline)                         % loop through 2 to end of timeline 
Ts(n) = (solarflux + IRs - (sigma*ems_mli*surfarea*(Ts(n-1)^4)))/(m*c) + Ts(n-1); 
end
```

Plotting your figure:

```
figure                                   % create a figure
plot(timeline,Ts)                        % plot timeline vs Ts
xlabel('seconds');                       % X-Axis label
ylabel('surface temperature (Kelvins)'); % Y-Axis label
```

Comment: Care to explain your change? Code-only answers are not very useful learning tools.